# 503 error while trying to access my first RESTful web service

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-apex, oracle12c, restful-url

i just created a RESTful web service following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkCvd6P8_OU) , when i try to test it i get a 503 error, i read somewhere that i have to set up the apex_listener by running the apex_rest_config.sql file, I did so but i get a got [these errors](http://imageshack.com/a/img593/2680/6onf.png) seing how i'm working with oracle12c, i think the errors are due to the new common and local users thing, so whats to do ? and what are the actual steps to follow ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would need to   correct the `defaults.xml db.servicename entry` and remove the other edits that you have done to the other files.

Please have a look [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/11122538)